# laravel 5.1 ajax error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

We are developing on laravel 5.1.

Although I made it I would like to make the acquisition of data in ajax,
It will be 500 (Internal Server Error).

Cause will have trouble do not know. The more of you understand who your professor, please.

route.php

```
Route::post('/getData', 'MasterController@getData');
```

view.blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    getData();
  });

  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
  });

  function getData() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/getData',
      data: {
        'id': $('[name=id]').val()
      },
      success: function(data, dataType) {
        alert(data);
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
      }
    });
  }
});
</script>
            : 
            :
    {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/commit')) !!}
            :
            : 
    {!! Form::close() !!}
            :
            :
```

MasterController.php

```
public function getData() {
    if (Request::ajax()) {
        var_dump('bbb');
    }
    else {
        var_dump('aa');
    }
}
```

Comment: If you get a HTTP 500 error you need to look into the serverlogs what it caused. We don't have a glass globe.

Comment: Try installing this to help debug: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar  - it is really great.

Comment: Do you get a "CSRF Token Mismatch Error"?

Comment: If you are using Firefox, press "Ctrl + Shift + Q" to get the Network developer tool, there you can observe the HTTP requests. Check the response you get.

Comment: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

Answer (score 2):

I believe since you are using the `Form` facade it is automatically inserting a `CSRF Token` of its own in addition to the AJAX header. The duplication of CSRF token confuses the middleware. The simple solution is to NOT use the `Form` facade:

```
<from action="{{url('/comment')}}" method="post" name="barform">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: @hiro would you please add the <head> section of `view.blade.php` to your question?

Comment: "\ App \ Http \ Middleware \ VerifyCsrfToken :: class," there was a change in the place where you have removed from the kernel.php. source return Response of controller.ph ('name', 200); If you change to, was operating normally. However, VerifyCsrfToken you want to use. Is there any idea something good?

Comment: It is not a good idea to remove the VerifyCsrfToken, your issue is simple and there is no need to expose your site to CSRF attacks. Have you included this in the <head> section of your `view.blade.php`: `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}"/>` ?

Comment: Thanks! I was able to resolve the problem. However, {!! Form :: text ('name') !!} I want to use.I think there is no way to solve anything?

Comment: You can use `$('[name=name]').val()`. How did you solve the issue?